# TypeError: programId.toBuffer is not a function when using web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress()

Tags: anchor, web3.js

I keep getting this error when trying to use findProgramAddress from solana's web3 js SDK:

```
TypeError: programId.toBuffer is not a function
```

Here is the cause of the problem:

```
public async createMerchantForUser(): Promise<[any, PublicKey, any]> {
    let [merchantPDA, merchantBump] = await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
      [
        Buffer.from(utils.bytes.utf8.encode("merchant")),
        //@ts-ignore
        this.userPubKey?.toBuffer(),
      ],
      this.programId
    );

    const createMerchantAccount = this.program.methods
      .createMerchant()
      .accounts({
        user: this.userPubKey?.toBase58(),
        merchantAccount: merchantPDA,
      })
      .signers([this.userKeypair]);

    let merchantState = await this.program.account.merchant.fetch(merchantPDA);

    return [createMerchantAccount, merchantPDA, merchantState];
  }
```

Here is the Nextjs error:

```
utils/BigBazaar/index.ts (131:44) @ _callee$

  129 | 
  130 |   public async createMerchantForUser(): Promise<[PublicKey, number]> {
> 131 |     let [merchantPDA, merchantBump] = await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
      |                                            ^
  132 |       [
  133 |         Buffer.from(utils.bytes.utf8.encode("merchant")),
  134 |         this.userPubKey?.toBuffer(),
```

Any help would be much appreciated

```
Edit, here is the code defines:

import rawIdl from "../IDL/BigBazaar_IDL_Devnet.json";

export class BigBazaar {
  constructor(
    readonly connection: Connection,
    readonly anchorWallet: AnchorWallet,
    readonly userKeypair = (anchorWallet as NodeWallet).payer,
    // readonly userKeypair: Keypair = Keypair.generate(),
    readonly userPubKey: PublicKey | null = anchorWallet.publicKey,
    readonly provider = setProvider(
      new AnchorProvider(connection, anchorWallet, {})
    ),
    readonly idl: Idl = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rawIdl)),
    readonly programId: string = idl.metadata.address,
    readonly program = new Program(idl, programId)
  ) {}
```

Comment: Could you show how `this.programId` and `this.userPubKey` are defined?

Comment: Please add to the question

Comment: @C.OG just did sry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PublicKey.findProgramAddress](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/PublicKey.html#findProgramAddress) method is expecting the `programId` to be a public key.

Option A:

```
export class BigBazaar {
  constructor(
  // code removed for brevity
  readonly programId: web3.PublicKey = new web3.PublicKey(idl.metadata.address), // <<< change here
```

Option B:

```
public async createMerchantForUser(): Promise<[any, PublicKey, any]> {
    let [merchantPDA, merchantBump] = await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
      [
        Buffer.from(utils.bytes.utf8.encode("merchant")),
        //@ts-ignore
        this.userPubKey?.toBuffer(),
      ],
      new web3.PublicKey(this.programId) // <<<< change here
    );
```

Comment: ah yeah it worked thank you so much

Note: u should change the type for Option A to PublicKey instead of string